# Search on string + 6 unknown chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a couple of divs which each has a data attribute: data-date.

Now I want to filter them based on a datepicker I just implemented. 
The date I get out of the datepicker is formatted like this: "12/25/2015".

```
        $('.reviewDatePicker').on('change', function () {
            var fromDate = $('#reviewDatePickerFrom').val();
            var toDate = $('#reviewDatePickerTo').val();
            if (fromDate != "" && toDate != "") {

            }
        });
```

The data-date attribute is a date + hours/min/seconds and looks like this: "12/25/2015 09:35:03". There is a reason for the extra specific value in the data attribute, it's to allow me to do more speicific searches as well.

What I would like to do though is to allow the datepicker to get all the divs which has a data attribute that starts with the value I get from the datepicker. My current search wont do, as it needs the entire string.

```
        $('#dropDownBoxDate').on('change', function () {
            var value = $('#dropDownBoxDate option:selected').val();
            if (value == 'All') {
                $('#reviewHistoryDiv tr').removeClass("hidden");
            } else {
                $('#reviewHistoryDiv tr').not($("#reviewHistoryDiv tr[data-date='" + value + "']")).addClass("hidden");
                $("#reviewHistoryDiv tr[data-date='" + value + "']").removeClass("hidden");
            }
        });
```

Comment: If I was not clear enough just ask and I'll try to make myself more clear.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/ or https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/ does this helps?

Comment: `$("div[data-date^='12/25/2015']")` will select every div whose `data-date` attribute starts with the date specified.

Comment: Thanks guys! I managed to figure it out with the help of that link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the appropiate jQuery selector. There is a "[starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)" selector:

Your code will be something like this:

```
$('#dropDownBoxDate').on('change', function () {
    var value = $('#dropDownBoxDate option:selected').val();
    if (value == 'All') {
        $('#reviewHistoryDiv tr').removeClass("hidden");
    } else {
        $('#reviewHistoryDiv tr').not($("#reviewHistoryDiv tr[data-date^='" + value + "']")).addClass("hidden");
        $("#reviewHistoryDiv tr[data-date^='" + value + "']").removeClass("hidden");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of the data attribute.

```
var date = $('#reviewHistoryDiv tr').data('date');
```

Check for existence

```
if(date.startsWith(value)){
    //found date
}
```